# How do I mark a test as inconclusive in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go

When writing tests in Go, how do I mark a test as inconclusive, i.e. as existent, but neither succeeding or failing, e.g. because it does not yet have an implementation?

I'm coming from a Node.js background, and e.g. in Mocha (a test-runner for Node.js) you can define a test without an implementation, and then Mocha marks this test as `pending`.

How can you do this with Go?

(If it makes any difference, I am using [gocheck](https://labix.org/gocheck) on top of `go test`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is not what you want but I'd use skip for this

```
func TestTimeConsuming(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
        t.Skip("skipping test in short mode.")
    }
    ...
}
```

This is likely controversial but I don't think tests should be inconclusive. They should Pass/Fail or Skip.